# Magento display static block in container2

Tags: layout, magento-1.7, php, static-block, magento-layout-xml

I have to many custom options on product page.

I would like to fill out the empty space on the left with a static block that appear only if more there is more than 4 custum options in product view.

http://goo.gl/Y7JMQf

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Display the static block content using

```
<div class="css_class_of_container" id="ID_OF_THE_STATIC_BLOCK_CONTAINER">
    <?php 
        echo Mage::getModel('cms/block')
            ->load('STATIC_BLOCK_IDENTIFIER')
            ->toHtml();
    ?>
</div>
```

Step2: Add css to hide the static block container by default using

```
.css_class_of_container { display: none;}
```

Step3. Use javascript to show and hide the static block based on the number of custom options available.

in `app/design/package/theme/catalog/product/view/options.phtml`

```
<?php if (count($_options)):?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <?php if(count($_options) > 4):?>
            //if you are using jquery
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
               jQuery("#ID_OF_THE_STATIC_BLOCK_CONTAINER").show();
            });
            //if using native javascript
            setTimeout('showhiddenStaticBlock()', 500);
            function showHiddenStaticBlock() {
                document.getElementById("ID_OF_THE_STATIC_BLOCK_CONTAINER").style.display = 'block';
            }
        <?php endif;?>
    </script>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: I've tried this but without success. I want to display The static block in container2 (Block after Info Column) on the left but only when I have more  than 4 custom options on the right container1(Product Info Column). This will fill up the empty space on the left.

Comment: Did you check whether the content from static block is rendering? Take the html source and make sure the `<div class="css_class_of_container" id="ID_OF_THE_STATIC_BLOCK_CONTAINER">` is there

Comment: fantastic!!!! to call the staticblock I've used: <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('my_static_block')->toHtml(); ?>